# How to display an image above the needed window in needed position?

Tags: bash

In Linux, I have bash script, which uses conky (for display image above windows in needed position of monitor) and xdotool (for check if needed window in focus, and if it is, then launch conky). So, can I do it in OS X? What should I use instead conky and xdotool? Maybe instead bash script Automator can do this job somehow?

P.S Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! Your question will get better answers if you add some details about which user problem  your script is going to solve. E.g. where is the needed window coming from, why do you want to put an image on screen etc.

Comment: I've found this app for Mac OS X which does the same job as `xdotool`: http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/ . Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: @patrix OK. I use deadbeef audio player, but artwork (cover) widget in there doesn't work as I want. In player is one plugin for cover widget and for display covers in playlist (column), so settings also identical for both. But for me it's unacepptable. And because that, I made a big shitty workaround with conky and xdotool for use that instead deadbeef's widget.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, and based on how I gotten your question, you probably need something alike [Clickclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/):

> “Cliclick” is short for “Command-Line Interface Click”. It is a a tiny shell/Terminal application that will emulate mouse clicks or series of mouse clicks (including doubleclicks and control-clicks) at arbitrary screen coordinates. Moreover, it lets you move the mouse, get the current mouse coordinates, press modifier keys etc.

it's what people advice to be the good compromise for `xdotool`.

As for `conky`, probably the closest alternatives for Mac would be:

- [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/)
- [GKrellM](http://gkrellm.srcbox.net/) - a single process stack of system monitors which supports applying themes to match its appearance to your window manager, Gtk, or any other theme.
- [XRG](http://www.gauchosoft.com/Products/XRG/)
- [Übersicht](http://tracesof.net/uebersicht/) - "Übersicht lets you run system commands and display their output on your desktop in little containers, called widgets. Widgets are written using HTML5, which means they

  - are easy to write and customize
  - can show data in tables, charts, graphs ... you name it
  - can react to different screen sizes"

But there are no direct alternatives, which fully accomplish the functionality of highly-customizable `conky` and powerful `xdotool`. You need to invent something else.

Comment: Sorry, but clickclick, from what I read in project page in github, doesn't have needed functionality. I cannot get which window in the focus now, it's program only about mouse, I guess.

For GeekTool thanks, it's probably can replace conky.

Comment: @AndreiDemin, as I mentioned at the end of my answer, there're no direct alternatives for Mac, so you need to use compromise variants. You may up-vote, if you wound my answer useful. Or shoot questions, if you gotten any.

Comment: @Farside There is also Übersicht http://tracesof.net/uebersicht/ as an alternative to conky.

Comment: Thank you @Rainer, I will take a look and can extend my answer. Good input!